# Amazon AWS: updated list of actions and services

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm working on automating access to some APIs thru a visual interface and thus would like to present the user with a user-friendly interface to call Amazon AWS APIs.
However the documentation uses human-readable formats but then the API need be called using more compact tokens.

I'd like to have a list of all the services, ideally:

ServiceID, Service name, Action Firendly Name, Action/Operation name, command line name

e.g. looking into CloudFront ListDistributions operation we can see that:

- Service is called "CloudFront" but the API endpoint is spelled lowercase "cloudfront"
- API requires calling GET /< version>/distribution  (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_ListDistributions.html )
- Commandline requires using the "list-distributions" form:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/list-distributions.html

similar thing with "ListPublicKeys" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_ListPublicKeys.html

Thus a table like this would help:

```
   ServiceID,  Service name, Action Firendly Name, Action/Operation name, command line name
   cloudfront, CloudFront,   ListDistributions,    distribution,          list-distributions
   cloudfront, CloudFront,   ListPublicKeys,       public-key,            list-public-keys
```

Comment: The AWS CLI already does something similar. You might be able to use their [data files](https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/develop/botocore/data) to extract this information. Your task also sounds similar to [aws-shell](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-shell).

Comment: aws-shell is a great tool and indeed we're trying to replicate something similiar for a very different context. However the botocore datafiles you pointed us at are 95% what we need! Unless something better comes in I'll make your note into a response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link posted from @John Rotenstein in the comment resolves the issue.

The [data files from Boto core](https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/develop/botocore/data) contain enought information to build the above mentioned table.